# Apache2 reverse proxy with SpringBoot backend

Tags: apache, spring-boot, https, apache2

I have a Spring Boot REST API that's using SSL. The backend is using port 8443 and I want to use Apache 2 reverse proxy so I can use a domain name like https://www.example.com/api/v1/ instead of https://localhost:8443/api/v1/.

Here is the Apache 2 config :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8443/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8443/
</VirtualHost>
```

and here is the SpringBoot config :

```
  port: 8443
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store: classpath:identity.jks
    key-password: secret
    key-store-password: secret
    trust-store: classpath:truststore.jks
    trust-store-password: secret
    client-auth: need
  servlet:
    context-path: /api/v1
```

When I'm accessing the URL https://www.example.com/api/v1/, I get the following error:

> Bad Request This combination of host and port requires TLS.

Comment: don't know well spring boot, but there is a standalone mode that doesn't need apache. Be sure not to try to combine standalone mode and apache

Comment: I'm only using Apache as a reverse proxy so incoming requests to https://www.example.com/api/v1/ are redirected to the standalone app running on https://localhost:8443/. I don't think there is a way to set this up on SpringBoot alone.

Comment: If think you needn't ssl enabled on spring boot because you configure https via apache. Then "the world" will access https://www.example.com/api/v1/ via https, and only in localhost will your api be accessed without ssl (only apache will access http://127.0.0.1:8443 without ssl encryption)